# polar plot : remove edge?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am brand new to Python. I used matplotlib to make a polar plot following the generic code:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0, color=[1, 0, 0])
```

Does anyone know if/how I could remove the green edge where the red slice is? I tried to control the axis color (set it to white and make it thick for example), but didn't manage so far.

thanks a lot!

[image: polar plot]

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, using contourf. Fiddly, but works